# Google Sheets Query to unpivot and fill null values

Tags: sql, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, flatten, google-query-language

I am writing a complex Google Sheets formula, which I think I can simplify using the Query function.  The Query formula takes two inputs: 1) data, 2) query.  The data consists of about 20 columns where the odd-numbered columns are categories and even-numbered columns are the values of that category.  (Note that there are a fixed number of rows, but various columns have variable number of non-blank entries.)

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1st Category | Value B1 | 2nd Category | Value D1 |
|  | Value B2 |  | Value D2 |
|  | Value B3 |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |

My dream output is as follows:

| Categories | Values |
| --- | --- |
| 1st Category | Value B1 |
| 1st Category | Value B2 |
| 1st Category | Value B3 |
| 2nd Category | Value D1 |
| 2nd Category | Value D2 |
| ...etc. | ...etc. |

Thanks for any thoughts !

Note: Common Table Expressions can't seem to be used in the Query function.

Add'l note: I don't mind and partially expect that I will have to repeat the query for the transformation of Column A and Column B ten times to get all the data, which is fine.  The simpler first-step question is how to do that.

Sample Google Sheets for reference/work: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/132E5CYwcv-ovWbZTnYqRMMqrR2X2pDv28Pj2bdW7w1k/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Data!B1:L5), "skipping 2", ))="",,
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Data!A1:L1), "skipping 2", ))&"×"&
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Data!B1:L5), "skipping 2", )))), "×"), 
 "where Col2 is not null order by Col1", ))
```

[image]

Comment: if you look back at my original post, then you'll have noticed it included, "@player0, are you there?".  (Someone immediately edited that out.)  I knew you'd come through for me.  Thank you !